# Entity Framework snapshot disadvantages

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are using ReadCommitted isolation level and sometimes we get table locks, so I decided to read about the new **Snapshot** isolation level. Seems to be better than ReadCommitted in every way. Exceptions occasionally occur, but they are easy to deal with the row version column in tables or a retry policy on failure (the last option I'm going to implement). Read mostly from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server

Can anyone with sufficient experience with snapshot provide any drawbacks?

Maybe I didn't notice the pitfalls.

Thanks in advance.

Our stack is Entity Framework v6, Entity Framework Core, SQL Server.

Comment: One possible drawback is the fact that snapshot isolation places a lot more stress on the Temp DB database - which is notoriously the source of a lot of issues already ....

Comment: Also, once the the ALLOW_SNAPSHSOT_ISOLATION database option is turned on, an additional overhead of 14 bytes per row is incurred.